# Php Mysql Database retrieval and display

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, data-retrieval

I've this problem with my PHP/SQL data retrieval from a remote database on my server.. The issue is that i created a database that has 2 columns (ID: Primary Key & Details: which holds Arabic Information that i want to be displayed on certain spaces on my website).

The problem is that i tried running a query to retrieve those data as follows: -

```
include ('config/setup.php');
##Database Retrieval Query: -
    ##High_Council_Query: -
        $id1='1';
        $high_council_query="SELECT * FROM home_content WHERE id=$id1";
        $data1 = mysql_query($high_council_query,$dbc) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
        $high_council_result= mysql_fetch_assoc($data1);

        $hcr = $high_council_result['details'];
        echo $hcr;
```

This is basically what i'm trying to do, i want to query the database to retrieve the value of details column where id = 1, and i want to take that value then view it on a certain spot where i've made CSS and HTML rules for using a $variable that has that single content..

Yet the problem is that it spits the result of the field too many times when i try to echo the $hcr which holds what i need it displays the same result over 6 times.. and ruins my page.. please help me with this error thanks ^_^

Comment: Have you checked that there is only one entry in the DB with the id of 1. E.g. is id a primary key?

Comment: Add a limit 1 at the end of your query

Comment: @JamesBirkett yes there is only one item with id of 1 since i have only two columns, the problem is that the result of the echo throws that single result about 6-7 times repeated screwing my view and referring to some logical problem..

RobertRozas i tried limit 1, it didn't solve the problem, cuz it still repeats the single result that there is at id=1.. the id=1 has only 1 result of details.. but it repeats it on the page for like 6-7 times as i mentioned before

Comment: In that case the query or at lest `echo $hcr` is being executed more than once. Please edit the question to show how this piece of code is run.

Comment: @JamesBirkett how do i fix that? i want only 1 single result that i can use later to save into a variable and put it on my website within its div tags with a proper Css format.. i'm trying to create a CMS

Comment: To check whether it's being run more than once, try echo'ing something just before `echo $hcr;`. If this repeats, it's run more than once, and fixing that is hard without seeing the rest of the code. If the new string is not repeated, the result string may contain the data that many times. Have you checked the data is not repeated in the field in the table?

Comment: @ShadyAbdAlrahim Please update your question with more information about when this section of code is run.

Comment: 1. I would definitely fire the collation-query _before_ the data retrieval query! 2. I think you have a loop around it which is missing in your code.

Comment: @MaX i tried echoing the $data1 variable and it spread on the same locations around the page the word "Array" for about 6-7 times too.. something is making this code loop or repeat itself, and i'm not sure what it is... i never inserted any loop instruction, and the code following this one, i mean by that the rest of the code does not contain any sort of looping + i made sure that the rest of the code is totally //COMMENTED out.. this echo shows that it repeats the same field over and around and i've no idea why.. i want it only retrieved once..

Comment: @flaschenpost i tried it without the collation query, but i need that query cuz i'm retreiving arabic language data, if i don't have that query on it will retrieve "????????????????????????????????????????????" 6-7 times also around the page..

Comment: @shady you Should use that query, but once after connecting, and before the first data retrieval. You fire first the select and then the collation. Still we can see no loop in your code, so it is impossible to help without seeing the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you understand why this data is being output more than once I'll give you some general debugging advice.

The aim in this case is to find out where the repeated data is coming from.

I would start by creating a test variable `$testing = 0` in the first line of the php file. Then replace

```
echo $hcr;
```

With:

```
$testing ++;
echo $hcr.' Loop:'.$testing;
```

This will determine if this section of code is being executed more than once. If it is it will also tell you how meany times.

If the string `Loop:...` is not displayed with the other instances of the data then you are useing `echo $hcr` in other places in your code.

Edit:

Because the counter is not being incremented the php file must be included more than once. Check for `include xyz.php;` in the main php file, probably `index.php`.

Comment: it repeated the same data on the page as you can see here http://wassatproject.com , but the loop shows on screen is equal 1!
but still the data is thrown all over the screen like garbage and i don't have any idea why.. what i have in the database is only the following arabic paragraph :- "لحزب الوسط قيادات و كوادر ذوي نجاحات و خلفية سياسية بارزة ,ابتداء من الهيئة البرلمانية وصولا إلى الملفات الفنية, تعرف على أعضاء الهيئة العليا."

That's all and i don't get why this errors are happening :/

Comment: James! You're right! it was included multiple times in many div tags but i didn't echo their content their, my bad i didn't know that the include was going to be global scoped.. but now there's 1 more problem i think that the echoed data within the only include left is delivered to the page in a corrupted encoding, my database is utf-general-ci and the collation of the field containing the data itself is same, and the mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci"); is not working as i try to post the result in a certain div where it should be.. it outputs "??????????????"

Comment: Character encoding is not something I know much about. If you can't work it out post a new question.

Comment: Thanks man ^_^, you've helped me alot.. i've fixed the problem with the encoding ^_^

Answer (score 0):

just delete  $high_council_result= mysql_fetch_assoc($data1); and simply use $data1 to view